# How to create a custom layouts for 404 page using NextJS?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I want to ask how I can make a different custom layout for my 404 page. I want to make a 404 layout that is different from the root layout.tsx.

My problem is I am still getting the component (footer or nav buttons) from my root layout.tsx to my custom 404 layout.

Here's my directory setup:

```
/app
   not-found.tsx
/components
   /JFCLayouts
      /JFCNotFound.tsx
```

```
// app/not-found.tsx
import Link from 'next/link'
import JFCNotFoundLayout from '@/components/JFCLayouts/JFCNotFound'

export default function NotFound() {
    return (
        <JFCNotFoundLayout>
            <div className='text-center'>
                <h2 className='text-3xl'>There was a problem.</h2>
                <p>We could not find the page you were looking for.</p>
                <p>Go back to the <Link href="/">dashboard</Link></p>
            </div>
        </JFCNotFoundLayout>
    )
}
```

```
// components/JFCLayouts/JFCNotFound.tsx
'use client'
import React from 'react'
import '../../styles/globals.css'
import './style.css'

const JFCNotFound = ({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) => {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
                <div className="jfc not-found">
                    {children}
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}
export default JFCNotFound
```

```
// app/layout.tsx
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import '../styles/globals.css'

import { Footer } from '../components/Footer'
import JFCProvider from '../redux/JFCProvider'

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: 'My App',
    description: 'My App'
}

export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) {

    return (
        <html lang="en">
        <Head>
            <meta http-equiv="ScreenOrientation" content="autoRotate:disabled" />
        </Head>
        <body suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
            <JFCProvider>
            {children}
            <Footer />
            </JFCProvider>
        </body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

I added also the snippet for my root layout. As we can see I have created a blank layout for my 404 page but the footer on my root layout is still rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a custom layout for your 404 page without including the footer or any other elements from your root layout, you need to ensure that your custom 404 layout (JFCNotFound.tsx) only includes the specific elements you want for the 404 page. Something like this,

```js
// components/JFCLayouts/JFCNotFound.tsx
import React from 'react'
import '../../styles/globals.css'
import './style.css'

const JFCNotFound = ({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) => {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
                <div className="jfc not-found">
                    {children}
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}
export default JFCNotFound
```

This will only includes the children passed to it and nothing else. This way, when you use this layout in your not-found.tsx file, only the content specific to the 404 page will be rendered.
This way when you use JFCNotFoundLayout in your not-found.tsx file, it won't include the footer.

```js
// app/not-found.tsx
import Link from 'next/link'
import JFCNotFoundLayout from '@/components/JFCLayouts/JFCNotFound'

export default function NotFound() {
    return (
        <JFCNotFoundLayout>
            <div className='text-center'>
                <h2 className='text-3xl'>There was a problem.</h2>
                <p>We could not find the page you were looking for.</p>
                <p>Go back to the <Link href="/">dashboard</Link></p>
            </div>
        </JFCNotFoundLayout>
    )
}
```

Comment: This is good and works, but needs some tuning. When clicking the back button or the link back from the 404 layout, the previous page can't be rendered and is wsod with a console error: "app-index.js:35 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <html> cannot appear as a child of <div>."